# Query in Elastic Search with some field and some condition?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have data about Product, which have some fields ( `_id, Shop, ProductVerion`...). It has indexed in Elastic Search. And I want to search products have max ProductVersion with Shop.

Ex:

```
Shop Amazon has 3 Version crawl product: 111,222,333.
Shop Ebay has 2 version: 222,444
Shop Alibaba has 2 version: 111, 444
```

Verions may may be the same.

And now, I want to get Products which have:

```
Shop Amazon and ProducVersion 333
or Shop Ebay and ProductVersion 444
or Shop Alibaba and ProductVersion 444.
```

But I don't know query that.
Help me, pls!!

Comment: It'd be easier if you show us your mapping

Comment: Please provide us some sample documents as json elements and your mappings of the relevant fields.

Comment: Please provide the details of your  elasticsearch version and the mapping that you have used/example document

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out with some example documents. I kept version field as numeric field.

These are example documents with which I tried

```
[
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "12334",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "shopName": "amazon",
      "version": 341
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "123",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "shopName": "amazon",
      "version": 3412
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1233",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "shopName": "amazon",
      "version": 341
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1238",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "shopName": "alibaba",
      "version": 34120
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1239",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "shopName": "alibaba",
      "version": 3414
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "123910",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "shopName": "alibaba",
      "version": 124
    }
  }
]
```

As @demas had specified I went ahead with terms aggregation and top hits aggregation

```
indexName/_search

{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "shop": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "shopName.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "product": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "version": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should provide you with the document that contains the highest product version number for each shop as shown below.

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "shop": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "alibaba",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "product": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 3,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "test",
                  "_type": "doc",
                  "_id": "1238",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "shopName": "alibaba",
                    "version": 34120
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    34120
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "amazon",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "product": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 3,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "test",
                  "_type": "doc",
                  "_id": "123",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "shopName": "amazon",
                    "version": 3412
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    3412
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I don't know if the answer is correct, I don't see the number of results displayed

Comment: Hi, I have only used aggregation to get the details. It has got documents of the products that has got highest version number for each shopName

Comment: You can also see the number of documents available for each shopName by checking the total field in aggregation result

Comment: I have tested this query, but it still seems to take the lower version. How to check the total field in aggregation result??

Comment: You can see the it by checking the total field for each shopname aggregation result. Can you provide your index mapping. There is a chance that the productVersion numbers are being saved in text format. That could be the reason why you are getting lower product version results.

Comment: @HiệpBạch Were you able to check?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you provide reproducible example, but it looks like you need to use [aggregation framework](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html): [term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
GET /_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "shops": {
        "terms": { "field": "Shop" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tops": {
           "top_hits": {
              "size": 100
           }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I did not see the mention Version here!